# How can a Python script know the path of the PHP file calling it?

Tags: php, python, exec, traceback, backtrace

I am executing a Python script from `foo.php` using `exec` and I want the Python script to know what directory the PHP call is originating from. In this example, it should be: `/www/includes`

```
# File tree
/script.py
/www/index.php
/www/includes/foo.php
```

## foo.php

```
var_dump( exec( "/usr/bin/python /script.py" ) );
```

## script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

print( os.getcwd() )
```

I found that `os.getcwd()` works great when the `foo.php` URL is called directly in the browser. I get the desired result: `/www/includes`

However, it *does not work* when `foo.php` is being called from another PHP file in a different directory, like `/www/index.php`.

## index.php

```
require_once '/www/includes/foo.php';
```

The Python script prints `/www` since that is where `index.php` lives.

## Problem

How can I get the Python script to return `/www/includes` when it's executed by `foo.php` no matter how the `foo.php` is being called? I have tried some `traceback` methods with no luck as I think it only applies to tracing errors.

Comment: you can't. `include()` in php acts as if the contents of the file being included were literally cut&pasted into the file doing the include. effectively your `foo.php` is PART of index.php

Comment: Thanks MarcB. That was very insightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your working directory to the directory of foo.php, which you should be able to do with chdir:

```
chdir (__DIR__); # change working dir to current directory.
```

In foo.php

Comment: This worked. The unfortunate thing with this solution is that it isn't purely resolvable in Python, the working directory has to basically be spoofed in PHP using `chdir()`. So taking into account MarcB's comment above, it seems as if a true traceback is never going to be possible since Python doesn't have the visibility into the PHP process of including/requiring other files. Thank you both.